# C# Правильная архитектура сервиса

Tags: c#

Нужно создать сервис, опрашивающий датчики и записывающий значения в базу. Подключение к датчикам 3х видов - ОРС, сом и ТСР.

А вот сама логика у них одинаковая - берем настройки сервера, подключаемся, получаем настройки из базы и прочее. Разница только в классе, отвечающем за общение с определенным интерфейсом.

Что в таких случаях является лучшей практикой? Создать каркас со всеми классами кроме различных и тупо копировать? Или можно класс для подключения к БД в dll обернуть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое - это создать 3 класса, реализующие подключения к различным типам датчиков с общим интерфейсом.

Остальная часть программы - работа с БД, логика опроса и т. п. про тип датчика ничего знать не должна.

DLL не требуется, как и отдельных программ. Ничего не мешает со всеми тремя типами датчиков работать одной и той же программе.